# k8s Ingress affects LoadBalancer on different domain

Tags: kubernetes

**TL;DR:** *A `nginx-ingress-controller` affects another `LoadBalancer` service on a different domain once every ~5 requests.*

I have a weird situation with Kubernetes on GCE, and I am stuck. I don't know if I have a configuration or if a have stumbled upon a (very severe) bug in k8s.

I have two LoadBalancer services, each with their own static IP and a DNS record pointing to them.

One LoadBalancer points (through it's selector) directly to a Deployment with my API webserver running on it, this is `api.domain.com`. This API cannot be behind an ingress controller due to a complex client side certificate authentication scheme, which is not (yet) possible with the nginx ingress.

The other LoadBalancer service points to a NGINX ingress controller. Which serves my website at `site.domain.com`. I use a standard `nginx-default-backend` to serve the 404 from the ingress controller.

The issue is that when I load the API (at `api.domain.com`) in a browser, **once every 3 or 4 times I hit refresh the 404 is served from `nginx-default-backend`.**

So once every 5 times or so, a page from a totally different domain (`site.domain.com`, `234.234.234.234`) is served on my API domain  (`api.domain.com`, `123.123.123.123`). I don't understand how this can happen.

Once I remove the `nginx-ingress-controller`, the API functions normally again. I'm really puzzled.

For the API:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 123.123.123.123
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
  - port: 443
```

And for the website:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-lb
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 234.234.234.234
  ports:
  - port: 443
    name: https
  selector:
    # Selects nginx-ingress-controller pods
    app: nginx-ingress-controller
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-controller
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-controller
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.17
        name: nginx-ingress-controller
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-lb
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: development
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.domain.com
    secretName: "site.domain.com-tls"
  rules:
  - host: "site.domain.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: website
          servicePort: http
```

What I have checked so far:

I have checked my DNS records using `host -a`, they are both correct. I checked for name collisions in the selectors using `kubectl get po -l app=website`, no collisions. I have checked the bound IP addresses:

```
> kubectl get svc
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)
api                     LoadBalancer   10.3.240.197   123.123.123.123  443:32126/TCP
nginx-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.3.253.16    <none>           80/TCP
nginx-ingress-lb        LoadBalancer   10.3.245.191   234.234.234.234  443:31051/TCP
website                 ClusterIP      10.3.254.180   <none>           80/TCP

> kubectl get ingress
NAME          HOSTS             ADDRESS           PORTS
ingress       site.domain.com   234.234.234.234   80, 443

> host api.domain.com
api.domain.com has address 123.123.123.123
> host site.domain.com
site.domain.com has address 234.234.234.234
```

All looks good to me.

Am I doing something wrong or is there something seriously wrong with k8s or nginx-ingress?

Answer (score 0):

<s>This was an interesting one.

I spent some time drawing diagrams and hypothesising why the error was occuring but the best answer comes from the [GLBC README](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce):</s>

> Don't start 2 instances of the controller in a single cluster, they
>   will fight each other

## Edit

I believe this behaviour is due to how the GCE loadbalancer forwarding rules work conflicting with the `nginx-ingress-controller` (or vice versa :) )

From what I can tell the GCE loadbalancer forwarding rules accept traffic on the same port number that is forwarded to cluster hosts i.e. `:443` in your example.

In the `nginx-ingress-controller` definition:

```
ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
```

We see that the nginx-ingress pods are listening on hosts at `:443`.
but the GCE load balancer is also forwarding to hosts at `:443`.

## Putting it all together

Imagine your API pods are deployed on some subset of cluster nodes say 3/4.
Then 3/4 times the GCE load balancer directs traffic to a host with a listening API pod - success!

But the 4th request routes to a node on port`443` with no API pod running. However an `nginx-ingress-controller` pod is listening and so responds to the request with `404`.

So the issue is not really one of DNS resolution as it might appear.

---

## References

The below quote from the k8s services [shortcomings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#shortcomings) seems to support my theory, as the `NodePort` values are unused, hence port forwarding is happening on the same port.

> This is not strictly required on all cloud providers (e.g. Google
>   Compute Engine does not need to allocate a NodePort to make
>   LoadBalancer work, but AWS does)

GCE forwarding rule creation
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/gce/gce_loadbalancer_external.go

Comment: I am running the [NGINX ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), not the GCE ingress. Also, I have only one ingress controller running. According to the documentation of nginx ingress, you can run a GCE and NGINX ingress together, as long as you define the class: `Note: Deploying multiple ingress controller and not specifying the annotation will result in both controllers fighting to satisfy the Ingress.`.